# Android actionBar spinner menu icon together the text

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I have a spinner menu on my actionbar, like below:

[image: spinner 1]

When I open it:

[image: spinner 2]

When I select a small iten, like "São Paulo", I get it:

[image: spinner 3]

But I want the icon of spinner like it:

[image: spinner 4]

My spinner layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/drop_down_states_item_height"
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_state_item_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drop_down_state_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_title"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drop_down_states_item_icon_margin_left" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How I can get the icon of spinner together the end of text?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It appears to wrap_content exactly as you specified.  I don't know that you could get it to "wrap_current_content" (or something), without changing it with code on change.

Comment: IIRC the ActionBar spinner stays as big as the longest string in your list and you need to create your own action bar of sorts

Comment: @tyczj do you have a start point of how to do it?